# Autologin in my app

Tags: android, autologin

My application will have one Activity (Register) which only appears once when the application is launched for the first time and will never appear anymore without dropping the data filled up in the registration Activity.

What should i do? Help me please, I'm new to Android and currently working on my thesis.

Comment: You can use Shared Preference to achieve this.

Comment: it's not clear, what you want.

Comment: edit your question title to brief the problem. It's obvious that you have problems with android, if you've tagged your question with `android` tag.

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).